A martingale puzzle about sum of expected squared bounds
I'm trying to get one of those "with $1-\delta$ probability, the following holds"-style bounds, and the following martingale problem looks solvable by some Freedman or Bernstein-style bound, but I couldn't quite figure out precisely how to apply those two inequalities to solve the problem.
EDIT: I did, thereby reducing this problem to solving a functional equation.
Namely, there are two sequences of random variables which may depend on past history, $\{Y_i,X_i\}_{1\le i\le T}$. The $X_i$ (random variables in $[-1,1]$) can be interpreted as the net payoff of a zero-mean bet, and the $Y_i$ (random variables in $[0,1]$) can be regarded as the magnitude of the zero-mean bet. More precisely, we have
1: No matter the past history, or what $Y_i$ (the bet magnitude) ended up being, $X_i$ has a mean of 0.
$$\forall i\le T:\mathbb{E}[X_i|Y_i,\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]=0$$
2: $X_i$ is always bounded in $[-Y_i,Y_i]$, which is why the value of $Y_i$ can be interpreted as the "bet size" which constrains how much we can gain or lose.
$$\forall i\le T:|X_i|\le Y_i$$
3: We run a betting strategy that is guaranteed to constrain the bet magnitude in terms of the payoff of the bets made so far. $\alpha$ is some number $\ge 1$. The following equation holds with probability 1.
$$\forall k\le T:\sum_{1\le i\le k}Y^{2}_i\le\alpha+2\sum_{1\le i\le k}X_i$$
The thing I'm trying to get is a $1-\delta$-style bound on the following term.
$$\sum_{1\le i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]$$
The fact that the bet magnitudes are random, instead of known ahead of time, means Azuma doesn't straightforwardly apply. It can apply, but it leads to very low-quality bounds because the third constraint, about the betting strategy we're implementing, effectively says that our bet magnitudes taper off as time goes by, so something much better should be possible. The Freedman and Bernstein inequalities look much more applicable, and I'm almost sure that a solution will involve them (EDIT: Freedman's inequality partially solved it), but I couldn't figure out how to straightforwardly apply them, because they effectively say that it's highly improbable that $\sum_{1\le i\le T}X_i$ is large and yet $\sum_{1\le i\le T}\mathbb{E}[X^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]$ is small at the same time, and I don't know how to transfer that fact to the type of bound I want.
EDIT: The problem has been reduced to "there's a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,T]$ which obeys the following constraint, provide an upper bound on the function $f$". The constraint is
$$f(3\delta)\le\alpha+\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+18\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)f(\delta)}$$
EDIT2: A suitable upper bound on the true function $f$ is:
$$f(\delta)\le 2\alpha+20\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+42$$

I solved it. Namely, I figured out how to reduce it from a problem about martingales to a problem about solving a functional equation, and then constructed an upper bound on the associated function. Solution as follows.
Let $f(\delta)$ be the unique function such that, with $1-\delta$ probability, we have
$$\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le f(\delta)$$
Given a $\delta$, let $x_{\delta}$ be defined as
$$x:=\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}\ln^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+2\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)f(\delta)}$$
An important thing to note here is that $x_{\delta}$ was selected precisely so that we have
$$\frac{x_{\delta}^2}{2f(\delta)+\frac{2}{3}x_{\delta}}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)$$
Now, by Freedman's inequality, applied twice, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i\le T}X_i\ge x_{\delta},\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[X^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le f(\delta))\le e^{\frac{-x_{\delta}^2}{2f(\delta)+\frac{2}{3}x_{\delta}}}=\delta$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i\le T}(\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]-Y^{2}_i)\ge x_{\delta},\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]-Y^{2}_i)^{2}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le f(\delta))\le e^{\frac{-x_{\delta}^2}{2f(\delta)+\frac{2}{3}x_{\delta}}}=\delta$$
Another two key things to note are that, because of $|X_i|\le Y_i$ we have
$$\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[X^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]$$
and also, because random variables bounded in $[0,1]$ have their variance being less than their mean, we can compute
$$\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]-Y^{2}_i)^{2}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]=\sum_{i\le T}var(Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1})\le\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]$$
So, putting it all together, there's $\le\delta$ probability of $\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]>f(\delta)$ and $\le 2\delta$ probability of $\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le f(\delta)$ and either $\sum_{i\le T}(\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]-Y^{2}_i)$ or $\sum X_i$ exceeding $x_{\delta}$.
So, with $\ge 1-3\delta$ probability, the following inequalities all hold.
$$\sum_{i\le T}\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}_{i}|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]\le x_{\delta}+\sum_{i\le T}Y^{2}_i\le x_{\delta}+\alpha+2\sum X_i\le 3x_{\delta}+\alpha$$
The first inequality was Freedman's inequality, the second was our assumed constraint on how the sum of $Y^{2}_i$ compares to the sum of $X_i$, the third is Freedman's inequality again.
Subsitituting in $x_{\delta}$, and using how $f(\delta)$ was defined, we arrive at the functional equation
$$f(3\delta)\le\alpha+\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)+18\ln\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right)f(\delta)}$$
And all that remains is figuring out an upper bound on this function $f$ from this functional equation.
Begin Phase 2!
In the space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,T]$, there is a unique fixpoint of the functional $\psi:([0,1]\to[0,T])\to([0,1]\to[0,T])$, which is defined as:
$$\psi(f)=\lambda x.\min\left(\alpha+\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+18\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)},T\right)$$
because in a neighborhood of 0, the $\ln$ part is large enough to saturate the bound, so all associated functions are $T$ in a neighborhood of 0. All fix-functions of the functional have their values everywhere determined by their values in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of 0, so since all fix-functions agree on a neighborhood of zero, all fix-functions of the functional must be identical. The true function $f$, whatever it is, must lie below the unique fix-function. Similarly, any function $g$ which has the inequality going the opposite way must lie above the fix-function.
Thus, any function $g:[0,1]\to[0,T]$ which obeys
$$g(x)\ge\min\left(\alpha+\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+18\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)g\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)},T\right)$$
is an upper bound on the true function $f$. Let $g$ be $\min\left(2\alpha+20\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+42,T\right)$.
Our goal then shifts to showing that
$$\min\left(2\alpha+20\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+42,T\right)\ge\min\left(\alpha+\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+18\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)\min\left(2\alpha+20\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+42,T\right)},T\right)$$
Let $y=\frac{3}{x}$ for convenience. Suppressing some min stuff, we can win by showing that
$$2\alpha+20(\ln(y)-\ln(3))+42\ge\alpha+\ln(y)+\sqrt{\ln^{2}(y)+18\ln(y)(2\alpha+20\ln(y)+42)}$$
We have that $20\ln(3)$ is slighly less than 22, so reshuffling a bit, our goal shifts to showing that
$$\alpha+19\ln(y)+20\ge\sqrt{\ln^{2}(y)+36\ln(y)\alpha+360\ln^{2}(y)+756\ln(y)}$$
Squaring both sides yields
$$\alpha^{2}+38\ln(y)\alpha+40\alpha+361\ln^{2}(y)+760\ln(y)+400$$
$$\ge 36\ln(y)\alpha+361\ln^{2}(y)+756\ln(y)$$
Which is easily verified to be true. Therefore the function $g$ is an upper bound on the true function $f$.
